# Are we allowed to wear shoes with our name on?

Tags: halal-haram, clothing, names

Are we allowed to wear shoes with my name Zakariya (زکریا) on them as my shoes are personalised is that haram?

Comment: I might add this; If someone has the name Abdu Allah and then wear this on his shoes or anywhere one should not forget that you will enter the toilet sometime. Many would consider enter the toilet forbidden if the name of Allah is visible (or spoken). So that might be something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

**In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful**

Uh, what an interesting query! As a short answer to your question as you asked:

> Are we allowed to wear shoes with our name on?

By paying heed to this issue which seems to be said as a hadith (tradition) that: "wearing fame/reputation clothes is considered as haram (forbidden) act." ,**therefore** it would be inferred from the mentioned narration that wearing such clothes can be deemed as a kind of fame or reputation clothes (which can attract the attention of others...), **as a consequence it can be considered as an impermissible act.**

Comment: So wearing any clothes with our names on is impermissible??

Comment: dear mate, occasionally, the religion give us a Formula of sth as a general formula (and we ourselves can recognise if ...)(and I've seen that: occasionally it doesn't illustrate regarding some miner items. / But according to my average knowledge: we can use the presented formula, how come? Actully, by paying heed to the Formula, we can recognize if what we are wearing can be deemed as a clothes of reputation which would attract the view of ... for the Shohrat (reputation or fame ...) / Good luck dear mate.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what others said. Just to add some value to the answers.

People and especially our kids do follow us. If we do anything suspicious that other people do not like or may have objection on, we should avoid that. Because if we are totally free to do what ever we want, then we can not stop or say others not to do something that we feel is not good. We are not just animals. We have a social life. We assist others and teaches to shape up a good society. Our practice should not confuse any non-muslim that if he is observing us as ideal people then at one stage he stops thinking about us as ideal religion and may be if he has plan inside to switch to Islam and just gets confused by our practices band cancel his plan. And we may not have such a good practices in front of others and can not have right to say that Yes Islam is very good. Because we can do anything anything we wish to do ? :)

> I have created this universe and life, so to see who does right deeds and follow good practices among you from on each other. [ Surah Mulk]

Hopefully this will clarify understanding and you may be able to answer others as well.